# how to get dataset name value from dictionary to operate upon

Tags: python, pandas

```
matches  = pd.read_csv("WorldCupMatches.csv")
players  = pd.read_csv("WorldCupPlayers.csv")
cups     = pd.read_csv("WorldCups.csv")

#create Dictionary of Datasets used in the project
projectDataSets = {'players':players, 'cups':cups, 'matches':matches} 

for dataSetNameStr, dataSet in enumerate(projectDataSets.items()):
   print(f"{dataSetNameStr} : {dataSet.count()}")

getting  TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

output Desired:

players: count of non nulls for players dataset

cups: count of non nulls for cups dataset

matches: count of non nulls for matches dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for key in projectDataSets.keys():
   print(f"{key} : {projectDataSets.get(key).count()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right. Just leave out `enumerate`

```
for dataSetNameStr, dataSet in projectDataSets.items():
    print(f"{dataSetNameStr} : {dataSet.count()[0]}")
```